# Installing numpy and pandas for python 3.5

Tags: python, numpy

I've been trying to install numpy and pandas for python 3.5 but it keeps telling me that I have an issue.

Could it be because numpy can't run on python 3.5 yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was corresponding with some ppl at python.org and they told me to use

`py -3.5 -m pip install SomePackage`

This works.

Comment: This works for Windows. For Linux this command  `python3.4 -m pip install SomePackage` should work. More information is here https://docs.python.org/3/installing/

Answer (score 2):

This is as a result of a Numpy distutils bug (which is already fixed in the development branch).

If you have brew:

```
brew install homebrew/python/numpy --with-python3
```

If you don't:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git
```

Comment: I tried typing this into the cmd. But it nothing happens. It just stays there and do nothing. How else can i install it?

Comment: Or should I just wait for numpy 1.10.2 to be released before trying to install it??

Comment: @jakewong apologies, I do not know why I automatically assumed you used a Linux/Unix based system. The second command should work on Windows. The first is Mac specific.

Comment: I tried `pip3 install git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git` in cmd, but it doesnt collect numpy. Not sure if there is anything wrong during my python installation, but when I use cmd to `pip install SomePacket` nothing happens. No additional message or anything.